# How do i access nested items in firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble to access my datafrom the firestore.
Adding data works perfectly well.
Accessing with an easy example works aswell:
[image: /cars/FaTFlIlSHl5qYSdyg0EZ]

```
Firestore.instance
              .collection('cars')
              .snapshots()

           Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['brandname']),
```

But when i want to access my nested data with the following structure:

[image: /Stände/Testing/Tue, 7.21.2020/Holstenstraße]

```
 Firestore.instance
              .collection('Stände')
              .snapshots(),
          
           Text(snapshot.data.document('Testing').collection('Tue, 
           7.21.2020').document('Holstenstraße')['Holstenstraße']['erdbeeren'] 
           ['erdbeerenAB']),
```

I get the error:

```
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'document'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: document("Testing")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the QuerySnapshot you can not directly perform another Firebase Query on it.

1). Let's say you want testing collection('Tue, 7.21.2020')'s all Documents.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Stände')
        .document('testing')
        .collection('Tue, 7.21.2020')
        .getDocuments().then((ds) {
          List<DocumentSnapshot> list = ds.documents;
    });
```

- it will contains 3 document as per your Database
- Then you can access by

  list.elementAt(index).data['Holstenstraße']['erdbeeren']
  ['erdbeerenAB']

2). If you want only one particular document => collection.document.collection.onlyOneDocument (documentID needed)

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Stände')
        .document('testing')
        .collection('Tue, 7.21.2020')
        .document('Holstenstraße').get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          print(ds.data['Holstenstraße']['erdbeeren']['erdbeerenAB']);
    });
```